# use System.Data.SQLite to read a row, get data from a few columns, add to a list of objects, loop to the next row

Tags: c#, sqlite, .net-6.0, system.data.sqlite

it IS getting data from the DB but what renders on the blazor end of things is the LAST row 13 times(that's actually the number of records in that table).

my simple class

```
public class ExportedFromDB
    {
        public string Id;
        public string ExportType;
        public string Path;
        public long Size;        
    }
```

the method:

```
        public List<ExportedFromDB> TalkToDBAndGetTheExportMetadata(string jobID)
        {
            ExportedFromDB exportedFromDB = new ExportedFromDB();
            var list = new List<ExportedFromDB>();
            int total;
            var dbPath = "c:\\ProgramData\\StorageQuest\\Rook Archive\\Jobs\\" + jobID + ".sqlite";
            var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbPath + ";Version=3;");
            
            using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
            {
                using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
                {
                    conn.Open();
                    command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Exported";
                    using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            exportedFromDB.Id = reader["Id"].ToString();
                            exportedFromDB.ExportType = reader["ExportType"].ToString();
                            exportedFromDB.Path = reader["Path"].ToString();
                            exportedFromDB.Size = (long)reader["Size"];                            
                            list.Add(exportedFromDB);
                        }
                    }
                    conn.Close();
                }
            }
            return list;
        }
```

in my Index.razor file:

```
                <div class="RookJobBlockRight">
                    @foreach (var exported in rookDashboardExtras.TalkToDBAndGetTheExportMetadata(job.ObjectId))
                    {
                        <p>exprt: @exported.Path</p>
                    }
                </div>
```

Expecting to generate a list of objects and to render the values from each of the objects in said list into my GUI.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry. I realized after I need to add a new object each time a record was read/added to the list.
new method:

```
        public List<ExportedFromDB> TalkToDBAndGetTheExportMetadata(string jobID)
    {
        ExportedFromDB exportedFromDB = new ExportedFromDB();
        var list = new List<ExportedFromDB>();
        int total;
        var dbPath = "c:\\ProgramData\\StorageQuest\\Rook Archive\\Jobs\\" + jobID + ".sqlite";
        var conn = new SQLiteConnection("Data Source=" + dbPath + ";Version=3;");
        
        using (var cmd = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
        {
            using (var command = new SQLiteCommand(conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                command.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM Exported";
                using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {   
                        list.Add(new ExportedFromDB 
                        {
                            Id = reader["Id"].ToString(),
                            ExportType = reader["ExportType"].ToString(),
                            Path = reader["Path"].ToString(),
                            Size = (long)reader["Size"]
                        });
                    }
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
        return list;
    }
```